# Error when trying to run a file .py to add data in database

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I create 2 files .py in an app of my project. my app si importXLS.

when I want to run my app, it does not work . 
first file goes and parse an excel file. It seems working well
second file should add each element of the first one and save it in database
This one is not working.

this is first file which parse excel file:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def is_empty(row):
    return all(cell.value is None for cell in row)


def is_empty_gl(row):
    return row[0].value is None


def has_empty_cells(row):
    return any(cell.value is None for cell in row)

# ----------------Chart of accounts--------------


def parse_coa():

    wb = load_workbook(filename='Chartofaccount.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    coa = []

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2, max_col=5):

        if is_empty(row):
            continue
        elif is_empty_gl(row):
            print('missing cell value found {}. Please fix and run again'.format(row[1].value))
#            exit()
        else:
            chartdictionnary = {
                'field_account': row[0].value,
                'field_account_libaccount': row[1].value,
                'field_type': row[2].value,
                'field_subtype': row[3].value,
                }
            coa.append(chartdictionnary)

    return coa
```

This is second file which is not working Error is :   db.connect()
NameError: name 'db' is not defined. But I don t know how to connect to data base (which is a sqlite for dev but should be another one in prod)

```
from read_data import parse_coa



db.connect()
for coa in parse_coa():
    coa = ChartOfAccount(field_account=coa['field_account'],field_account_libaccount=coa['field_account_libaccount'],
                         field_type=coa['field_type'], field_subtype=coa['field_subtype'])
    coa.save()

db.close()
```

Add data to database

Comment: Is your code running under `./manage.py shell`, or as part of a custom Django management command (`./manage.py mycommand args ...`). If not the Django environment won't be properly initialized and most things won't work.

Comment: Why have you called db at all? That is not how you do things in Django. What gave you the idea you needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Following strictly your code posted here, you have never defined the `db` class.

Have you imported in some part of the code? Like:

```
from packet import database as db ?
```